# How can I get a Timestamp of my OPC UA server?

Tags: python, opc-ua

I need to get a timestamp, with date, of my OPC UA Server, preferably in the right timezone.

```
print(opcua.ua.DataValue())
```

I've tried doing this, but I won't get a timestamp.

```
DataValue(Value:Variant(val:None,type:VariantType.Null), StatusCode:StatusCode(Good))
```

If possible I would like to get it at the same time as this.

```
print(self.client.get_values(nodes))
```

Answer (score 0):

All servers contain a `CurrentTime` Node that is part of the `ServerStatus` Object.

It can be found by navigating `Server` -> `ServerStatus` -> `CurrentTime`.

It always has the same `NodeId`: `i=2258`